# How to disable key repeat in SDL2?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

There used to be a function named `SDL_EnableKeyRepeat()` in SDL, but not anymore in SDL2.

I searched around in SDL2-wiki but failed to locate anything relevant.

Any ideas?

Comment: If these answers really are the best solution, that just seems wrong.  "key down" should mean when the key is physically pressed down.  Any type of automated repeating should be an optional behavior.

Comment: @xaxxon "when the key is physically down" - It is physcially still pressed down. This is standard hardware behaviour in the keyboard itself that so long as the key is down, it generates a the-key-is-down interupt.

Answer (score 41):

When handling a keyboard event, just filter out any events that are repeat events, i.e. check the `repeat` field of the `SDL_KeyboardEvent` of the `SDL_Event` union.

For example:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
  if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
    quit = true;
  }
  if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.repeat == 0) {
    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_d)
      debug = debug ? false : true;
    // ... handle other keys
  }
}
```

See https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_KeyboardEvent

Comment: what about the all the events generated that are not processed because of repeat? wouldn't be just better having a way to disable "key repeat" events? And just receiving key up/down?

Answer (score 6):

You may be better served by the [SDL_GetKeyboardState](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) function which tells you all the keys that are pressed. You can also just check the `repeat` flag in the event and ignore when repeat is true.

Comment: Very nice lateral approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself, by adding your "down" key into a list and removing them when you catch  a KEY_UP and at each frames you can iterate your list to know which key is still down.

Comment: That sounds totally doable, but isn't this supposed to be a standard function? I was just looking for the one that impersonates SDL_EnableKeyRepeat:) Thanks for answering.

Comment: what about the all the events generated that are not processed because of repeat? wouldn't be just better having a way to disable "key repeat" events? And just receiving key up/down?