# How to disable key repeat in SDL2 text input

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I would like to take over how keys repeat in my program, which means disabling how SDL2 does it automatically.

It's possible to ignore `SDL_KEYDOWN` repeat events since the `Event` union member `key` has a `repeat` boolean you can filter with (this question explores that solution: [How to disable key repeat in SDL2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156815/how-to-disable-key-repeat-in-sdl2)).  But `SDL_TEXTINPUT` events do not have the same info available in them, and so it's impossible to filter out characters that have repeated.

Is there any way to outright disable key repeating?

Comment: After researching the library's code and chatting on irc, there isn't a (easy) way to disable key repeating.  So what I've had to do is live with it, and ensure text editing buttons like backspace and the arrow keys don't ignore the repeat flag, so they "feel" the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is currently no simple way to do this, and because I need this as well I made a ticket: https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4598

If you have another additional use case why you want this, feel free to add a comment on the bug ticket so the developers get an idea what sort of uses this is important for. (Mine is providing an emergency disable option for people with keys-getting-stuck bluetooth keyboards on android who want to still be able to type texts without major accidents)

Answer (score -2):

Well in SDL lib might be a solution, but you can also add some simple c++ code to resolve your problem. For example if you don't want to play with     SDL_KEYUP you can just do something like this:

```
//before loop 
int keypress_control = 0;
//much Code, loop etc.
//
swich(event.type)
case SDL_KEYDOWN :
/*if or switch again as you want */if (keypress_control == 
2)
{
/*Code here*/ 
keypress_control = 0;
}
else 
{
keypress_control = 0;
} 
}
//after switch but Still in program loop
Keypress_control++;
//
//
```